# Specifying a size when displaying an image associated with a taxonomy through ACF

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I created a "books" custom taxonomy for my "book" CPT. Using ACF, I assigned an image to each my custom taxonomy terms.

I have a page where I display all my "books" terms as images. It works but now I want to specify a particular size to these images. The code of the page:

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'books';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_terms) {
    $taxonomy_image = get_field( 'taxonomy_image', 'books_'.$tax_terms->term_id );
    $taxonomy_image_url = $taxonomy_image['url'];               
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $taxonomy_image_url; ?>" alt="" />
    <?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

I think the [ACF doc page about images](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/image/) contains the key to what I'm trying to do - especially the part about image size, but I can't seem to find a way to integrate it to my code successfully. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you currently have the field set to return the image object, if you scroll down to the bottom of the page you linked you'll see an example object:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 540
    [alt] => A Movie
    [title] => Movie Poster: UP
    [caption] => sweet image
    [description] => a man and a baloon
    [url] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up.jpg
    [sizes] => Array
        (
            [thumbnail] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up-150x150.jpg
            [medium] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up-300x119.jpg
            [large] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up.jpg
            [post-thumbnail] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up.jpg
            [large-feature] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up.jpg
            [small-feature] => http://localhost:8888/acf/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/up-500x199.jpg
        )

)
```

so for a specific size you want to replace `$taxonomy_image['url']` with `$taxonomy_image['sizes']['thumbnail']`, where `thumbnail` is the desired size key.